# Ramda - How to validate an object?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I would like to refactor the code below using Ramda. I want to compare the list of keys and values with the data that I receive from the server, if the data matches, the function run. To do this, I created a list of keys and values and using `include()` I get a `boolean`.

```
//example data

data = { fieldName: 'secretKey', fieldValue: 'ymt' } 


const fieldNames = ['secretKey', 'activateCode']
const fieldValues = ['ymt', 'IdTYj']

if ( fieldNames.includes(data.fieldName) || fieldValues.includes(data.fieldValue)) {
    yield put(isLoading(true));
}
```

Instead of `include()` I used `R.include` but I always get `false`

```
const field = R.equals( fieldNames, data.fieldName) // return false
```

Which method in Ramda is more suitable for comparing keys and values to return a `boolean`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather do something alike,
You need to `R.flip(R.includes)` to use it
within your algorithm

```js
const put = R.identity;
const isLoading = R.identity;

function* validate(data) {
  const keys = ['secretKey', 'activateCode'];
  const values = ['ymt', 'IdTYj'];
  
  const predicate = R.where({
    fieldName: R.includes(R.__, keys),
    fieldValue: R.includes(R.__, values),
  });
  
  if (predicate(data)) {
    yield put(isLoading(true));
  }
};

const iterator = validate({ 
  fieldName: 'secretKey', 
  fieldValue: 'ymt',
});

console.log(
  iterator.next().value
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: The point being that `R.includes` takes `needle` (the single item you're looking for) first, then `haystack` (the list of terms that might or might not include `needle`) second.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `where` e.g.

```js
const check = where({ username: either(equals('foo'), equals('FOO'))
                    , password: either(equals('bar'), equals('BAR'))});

check({username: 'foo', password: 'qux'}); // false
check({username: 'qux', password: 'bar'}); // false
check({username: 'foo', password: 'bar'}); // true
check({username: 'foo', password: 'BAR'}); // true
check({username: 'FOO', password: 'BAR'}); // true
```